# I'm getting identical values for element.scrollWidth and element.offsetWidth, in my Angular component

Tags: angular

I have a container in my component, that contains some content inside it. The container has a display of flex and the items inside it have fixed widths and heights. The content overflows the container on the x axis and thus I have applied an overflow of hidden to the container.

```
<div class="container">
  <article>Content...</article>
  <article>More content...</article>
</div>
```

I would like to get the width of the content that is currently displaying on the view port but I also want to get the full width of the container including the overflowed content and all margins and borders. I'm trying to do this using the offsetWidth and scrollWidth properties like so...

Inside my component.ts file, I have imported ElementRef.

In my constructor I have then added it like so..

```
public container;

constructor(private el: ElementRef) {...}
```

However, when I try to get the offset as well as scroll widths, I get identical values.

```
this.container = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.container');

console.log(this.container.offsetWidth)
console.log(this.container.scrollWidth)
```

What am I doing wrong?